# Hat control icon goes offscreen

Tags: bug, status-declined, winter-bash, winter-bash-2021

It appears that it is impossible to rotate or resize the hat once it is in a certain position because the control is inaccessible and offscreen.

[image: updated image]

Is there a better way to fix this other than having to refresh the page and losing the rotation and size of the hat (as I ended up doing)? Thanks.

Comment: Corresponding issue for 2022: [Unable to adjust my hat as hat control is hidden](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384762/335251)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry about that. The hat picker modal was refactored this year, and this was an unintended side-effect. I'll tweak the padding around the hat to give it a little more room, but beyond that, we unfortunately have no time to address the mentioned issue.

Comment: any idea about WHY the controls overflowing past the modal is hidden only for some users though? See for example [this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Answ7.png) I saw in another post.

Comment: @SPArcheon no idea. Must be a difference between browsers, since the code being spit out is the same. FWIW, the modal here was rewritten [into stacks](https://stackoverflow.design/) this year (related to things like this).

Comment: Thank you. I realized it was different last year and wondered what had changed. (It makes a lot more sense now.)

Answer (score 3):

I looked at possible client side fixes since I have the same issue but Yaakov hasn't got time for this right now and had to decline a fix.

You should be able to add the following style to the page using something like Greasemonkey as a workaround.

```css
.s-modal--dialog.wmx9.w100{
   overflow: visible;
}
```

this was tested on Firefox, should work on other browsers too.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to test this out and add it in if/when I get a chance. If you don't see anything on this in the next week, ping me in chat please.

Comment: Signpost to Adam Lear's [post that references this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/385162).