# Unable to adjust my hat as hat control is hidden

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, winter-bash, winter-bash-2022

I can't adjust the position of my hat as the hat control overflow is hidden.

> [image]

> [image]

I'm using Safari v16.1 running on macOS.

Comment: Yes, that's the same bug which was never fixed, but since it was declined better leave this one open, for the slim chance they'll fix it this year. :/

Comment: You can drag the whole thing down with the mouse, and the controls will appear, so the bug is not really critical. (Easy workaround exists.)

Comment: The related bug report from last year: [Hat control icon goes offscreen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/373059/335251)

Comment: @AdamLear I see many bugs are being sent for review, which is good, however it's four days since a winter bash bug was actually fixed. Since this is a temporary event that ends very soon, is there a chance to "prioritize" the bugs, or however it's called, so they have chance to be fixed before the event ends?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many thanks to [SPArcheon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/171199/sparcheon) for the [proposed fix](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/374109) last year.

It's live in production now.