# Unable to scroll down to see all my hats in the Winter Bash hats pop-up

Tags: bug, winter-bash, winter-bash-2022

I'm unable to scroll down my list of hats in the Winter Bash hats pop-up as it scrolls the background (my activity page) instead.

> [image]

This seems to be a very recent occurrence, perhaps due to [a recent bug fix(?)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384762/unable-to-adjust-my-hat-as-hat-control-is-hidden/385162#385162) – though I really appreciate that *that bug* was fixed.

This can be reproduced on Safari for iOS (latest version).

Comment: Reproduced on my mobile too.

Comment: Reproduced on Chrome on Android too.

Comment: An antimated gif of the problem on iOS 16.1.2 https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfMBq.gif